# Is it possible to compute with high accuracy if a series converges using Haskell?

Tags: haskell, math, functional-programming

I am trying to develop a custom math library in Haskell that encodes expressions for a project. I'm wondering whether it is possible to determine (with high accuracy) if a mathematical from n to infinity converges or diverges. I have a sigma sum function available in my library, which I initially thought I could use to determine if a series converges by finding the difference of the sigma sum from some n to say something like 1000 and the sum from the same n to something much higher 100000. However, while I thought this might work at first, I realized this wouldn't work as any constant times a convergent series is also convergent and will wind up increasing the difference in the sums I was using to determine if a series is convergent or not.

This is what I have:

```
isConverging :: String -> a -> Expr a -> Bool
isConverging x a expr = if abs((eval (Map.fromList [(x, a)]) $ sigma x a (1000) expr) - (eval (Map.fromList [(x, a)]) $ sigma x a (100000) expr)) <= 1.0e-3 then True else False
```

As a result, I'm wondering if there is a better way to compute if a series likely converges. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Minor, tangential note: `if foo then True else False` is always redundant -- it is the same as `foo`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests

Comment: Your question reminded me of this: http://conal.net/papers/compiling-to-categories/

Comment: Also tangential, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270933/should-i-answer-is-it-possible-type-of-questions

Comment: I suppose this depends very much on how complicated your expression language is. If your expressions are, say, all linear, then it's easy as heck (the constant 0 is convergent and nothing else is); while if your expressions are Turing-complete it's obviously undecidable. (Likely any expression language complicated enough to be fun to use is going to leave this question undecidable in general.)

Comment: You can't use any delta-based system to detect convergence. The [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) famously doesn't converge, and the delta between elements has 0 as its limit.

Comment: This was my fear in wondering whether it'd be possible to find convergence this way. My expressions are too complex to code the multiple convergence tests, so I was just looking for something that works most of the time. For instance, maybe knowing that 1/x^1.1 converges while maybe not being able to determine that 1/x^1.000000001 does